# How to remove empty results (NULL values) in SQL

Tags: sql

```
SELECT 
    P.PRODNR, P.PRODNAME,
    (SELECT SUM(QUANTITY) 
     FROM PO_LINE POL
     WHERE P.PRODNR = POL.PRODNR) AS TOTALORDERED
FROM 
    PRODUCT P
WHERE 
    P.PRODNR IN (SELECT P.PRODNR
                 FROM PO_LINE
                 WHERE QUANTITY >= ALL (SELECT QUANTITY
                                        FROM PO_LINE))
```

I need to get the table where `TOTALORDERED` column should not give me any NULL values. I tried `IS NOT NULL` in all both subquery and main query but did not work.

First attempt:

```
SELECT
   P.PRODNR, P.PRODNAME,
   (SELECT SUM(QUANTITY) 
    FROM PO_LINE POL
    WHERE P.PRODNR = POL.PRODNR) AS TOTALORDERED
FROM
    PRODUCT P
WHERE 
    TOTALORDERED IS NOT NULL
    AND P.PRODNR IN (SELECT P.PRODNR
                     FROM PO_LINE
                     WHERE QUANTITY >= ALL (SELECT QUANTITY
                                            FROM PO_LINE))
```

Error:

> Unknown column 'TOTALORDERED' in 'where clause'

Comment: You should explain what you want to achieve exactly. What you have is: look at all orders and find the highest amount that was ever ordered. Let's say that usually its just 2 or 3 pieces ordered per product, but two times it happened that 15 pieces of a product got ordered. So you get that 15, find the two products for which these special orders occurred and then you look at their total order amounts, which may be 100 for product A and 55 for product B for instance. Is this already what you want?

Comment: `TOTALORDERED` is unknown by the way, because the `WHERE` clause happens before the `SELECT` clause. Which DBMS are you using? You should always tag your SQL requests with your DBMS. Otherwise you may get answers that don't work for you.

Comment: question is to to retrieve the number and name and total ordered quantity of all
products that have been ordered, except for the product with the smallest outstanding
ordered quantity. With the code I have , I also get the products that has never been ordered. and I would like to get rid of those products in the result table.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you working with?

Comment: Erm, my English fails me :-) "the smallest outstanding ordered quantity"? This is you want to look at the total amount ordered per product, then see how much has been delivered and how much is still outstanding? And if there are products where all orders have already been met, then there is no outstanding order, so the amount is zero, and you want to exclude all products with an open amount of zero? If, however, all products still have outstanding amounts and the least amount is 10 pieces, you want to exclude the products with an open amount of ten pieces? This sounds quite weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your error was caused by using `TOTALORDERED` alias in the where section and it's not yet available in there.

```
Select * from (
    SELECT P.PRODNR, P.PRODNAME,
    (SELECT SUM(QUANTITY) FROM PO_LINE POL
    WHERE P.PRODNR = POL.PRODNR) AS TOTALORDERED
    FROM PRODUCT P
    join (SELECT PRODNR
                    FROM PO_LINE
                    WHERE QUANTITY >= ALL
                                    (SELECT QUANTITY
                                    FROM PO_LINE
                                    )
          )pl on pl.PRODNR = P.PRODNR
)t 
WHERE TOTALORDERED is not NULL
```

Update: new answer based on query in question

```
select * from (
SELECT 
    P.PRODNR, P.PRODNAME,
    (SELECT SUM(QUANTITY) 
     FROM PO_LINE POL
     WHERE P.PRODNR = POL.PRODNR) AS TOTALORDERED
FROM 
    PRODUCT P
WHERE 
    P.PRODNR IN (SELECT P.PRODNR
                 FROM PO_LINE
                 WHERE QUANTITY >= ALL (SELECT QUANTITY
                                        FROM PO_LINE))
)s
WHERE TOTALORDERED is not NULL
```

Comment: it gives me this error : Error: Unknown column 'P.PRODNR' in 'field list'

Comment: @Greencolor Do you have PRODNR field in PO_LINE table?

Comment: yes sir, i have

Comment: @Greencolor I updated my answer also add another answer for your question.

Comment: Sorry My apologies, it returns the value only for one product. But I have 43 rows with NULL values. Out of 43 19 is NULL value and 24 has totalordered value

Comment: @Greencolor you want to see  all records?

Comment: Updated one gets 21 rows as a result, could please explain what  ")s " means?

Comment: @Greencolor it's an alias for the subquery.

Comment: I got it. Thank you so much